# What does cycles mean in perf report?

Tags: linux, x86-64, profiling, perf

I wrote code that inserts data into an array semi randomly in one loop and read it back in another. Perf stat says 70% of backend cycles were stalled. Using getclocktime I saw the insert code was about 450ms while the read code was about 300 which totals to 750ms. sys time was 35ms.

`perf report` says the read code took %5 of the time which makes no sense as get clock time says it took 300ms of the 750ms. That's about 40% of the total runtime. perf report says insert took 57% of the time which is roughly correct (almost 60% of the time)

Perf woke up 12 times to write samples. I tried increasing it to 120 and it says 4.9% which is nowhere near 40%

What is perf report measuring?

Comment: Do you have a [mcve]?  What hardware was this on?  Are you counting total time with perf` vs. only user-space time (not including time spent handling page faults) with `getclocktime`?  What's `getclocktime` anyway; there's no man page for it on my desktop.  The first access to a page is a lot slower, but most of the time is spent page-faulting into the kernel and having it zero pages.

Comment: Depending on your `perf_event_paranoid` setting, `cycles` is either unhalted core clock cycles in user+kernel space (while this process is `current`), or just in user-space.